# How to create a variant model using multiple arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, e-commerce

```
    *From*
    let size = ["Small", "Medium", "Large"]
    let color = ["Green", "Blue", "Red"]
    let mat = ["Wood", "Glass", "Plastic"]

    *To*
    let _ = ["Small", "Green", "Wood"]
    let _ = ["Small", "Green", "Glass"]
    let _ = ["Small", "Green", "Plastice"]
    let _ = ["Small", "Blue", "Wood"]
    let _ = ["Small", "Blue", "Glass"]
    let _ = ["Small", "Blue", "Plastic"] and so on.
```

I will like to create a table using the above arrays and have something similar to the image.

[[image: Shopify sample1]

Comment: So you want to create a data structure (the cartesian product) of all the arrays? This might grow rapidly in size, so maybe it would be better to just calculate it "on the fly".

Comment: I think you are looking for some kind of `sort` instead. Arrays are not good structure for the reason you are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

As a simple experiment you can define nested loops to build that output:

```
var combined = [[String]]()
for size in sizes {
    for color in colors {
        for material in materials {
            combined.append([size, color, material])
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Result]

## BUT!

It can grow to a massive array and arrays are not for these kind of tables. You should. consider using a structure like a simple struct or even a dictionary instead.

For example, take a look at this struct:

```
struct Product: Codable {
    let size: String
    let color: String
    let material: String
}
```

So you can populate it with the previous code like:

```
var products = [Product]()
for size in sizes {
    for color in colors {
        for material in materials {
            products.append(Product(size: size, color: color, material: material))
        }
    }
}
```

And will you have:

[image: Demo 2]

It is now searchable, extendable, sortable, storable, and it has many many other features out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Or use the generic approach using higher functions:

```
extension Collection where Element: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    func combinations() -> [Element] {
        reduce([.init()]) { result, element in
            result.flatMap { elements in
                element.map { elements + CollectionOfOne($0) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let combinations = [size,color,mat].combinations()

for combination in combinations {
    print(combination)
}
```

This will print:

> ["Small", "Green", "Wood"]
> ["Small", "Green", "Glass"]
> ["Small", "Green", "Plastic"]
> ["Small", "Blue", "Wood"]
> ["Small", "Blue", "Glass"]
> ["Small", "Blue", "Plastic"]
> ["Small", "Red", "Wood"]
> ["Small", "Red", "Glass"]
> ["Small", "Red", "Plastic"]
> ["Medium", "Green", "Wood"]
> ["Medium", "Green", "Glass"]
> ["Medium", "Green", "Plastic"]
> ["Medium", "Blue", "Wood"]
> ["Medium", "Blue", "Glass"]
> ["Medium", "Blue", "Plastic"]
> ["Medium", "Red", "Wood"]
> ["Medium", "Red", "Glass"]
> ["Medium", "Red", "Plastic"]
> ["Large", "Green", "Wood"]
> ["Large", "Green", "Glass"]
> ["Large", "Green", "Plastic"]
> ["Large", "Blue", "Wood"]
> ["Large", "Blue", "Glass"]
> ["Large", "Blue", "Plastic"]
> ["Large", "Red", "Wood"]
> ["Large", "Red", "Glass"]
> ["Large", "Red", "Plastic"]